# keylogger with a certain time period

Tags: python-3.x

How to stop keylogger by using time or datetime and without pressing any keyword in keyboard. My code is:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
def on_press(key):
    print('{} pressed.'.format(key))
def on_release(key):
    print('{} released.'.format(key))
    if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting...')
        return False
listener=keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press,on_release = on_release)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is the expected behaviour? You want the Listener to stop on a certain date and time, that's it?

Comment: The above function should be terminated in a certain time for example give it for 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is using a simple `time.sleep()` method, along with the `with` keyword. Something like:

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    time.sleep(60)
```